# Timeout waiting for SSH when trying to ssh from private AWS Ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have a situation here where I need to ssh public instance from private instance. Both instances are in different vpc.

I setup Nat gateway, vpc peering connection, route tables and security group of public instance which allows all traffic over ssh (0.0.0.0/0).

1. private instance is in VPC-A.  I am able to ssh to private instance Pr1 from bastion host.
2. Now I am trying to ssh to public instance in another vpc VPC-B from instance Pr1.

Now sure what is missing, I am getting ssh timeout.

I am able to ssh to that instance from my laptop but not from private instance.

curl google.com responds means I can access internet from private instance.

Can someone please suggest what can be missing ?

Comment: How do you try to ssh? Using public IP address?

Comment: yes, e.g. `ssh -i <key>  ubuntu@<ip address> `
               

I also tried to ssh private instance but same problem.

Comment: What are seciuritie groups on the public instance?

Comment: `101 SSH (22) TCP (6) 22 CIDR  Allow`













I found the problem and solution,  above entry was missing from Network ACLs.

Thanks.

Comment: In general, you should _not_ modify Network ACLs unless you have a very specific reason (eg to create a network DMZ). Use Security Groups instead of Network ACLs.